# How do I check to see if a linked list is empty?

Tags: python, hashmap

I have a program called `Hashmap.py` that imports a module called `OList.py`.
Hashmap creates an array and assigns each spot in the array to an empty list. Every spot that is taken up in the array is sorted like this: `[KEY, VALUE, OList()]`.

I'm working on a delete method to change the list to `None` if the `OList` is empty when I call the delete method. However I don't know how to determine if my `OList` linked list is empty or not.

`if self.array[index][2] == []` seems to not work.

Indices: `(0=key, 1=value, 2=OList())`

```
def __delitem__(self, key):               
    if self.debug:
        print("__deleting__ " + key)
    index = self.gethash(key)
    if not self._occupied(index):
        return 
    elif self.array[index][0] == key:
        if self.array[index][2] == []:
            self.array[index] = None
        else:
            self.array[index][0] = '*#*'
            self.array[index][1] = '***'
    else:
        self.array[index][2].delete(key)
```

Comment: How is `OList` implemented? Most data structures in Python are "falsy" if they're empty, so you would test this like `if if self.array[index][2]`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe your `OList` data-structure implementation in more detail. To make a container object's "truthiness" be considered empty, you should implement a `__bool__()` method and/or a `__len__()` method - see [Emulating Container Types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) in the documentation.

Comment: @martineau added a  __len__() method in my OList class and just checked if the length was less than 1 and it works now. Appreciate it!

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my comment (or what you read in the linked documenation). You don't need to check that actual length by calling `len()`. Just check the container's "truthiness" — i.e. `if my_olist: ...`.